# Need suggestions on open source libraries which can be used develop applications like google goggles etc

Tags: computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, search-engine

I am looking for a open source library which can help me in creating Visual Search applications similar to google goggles.
Preferred Lang: Java, Ruby, Python.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) in Python or Java. This is the best open source for computer vision. It can be interfaced with some other librairies if needed